# Error in mysql stored procedure with c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to use a stored procedure in mySql and it must return `identity_scope()`. I try this but don't work:

---

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `InsertVideo`(  
  OUT out_scope_id        INT,
    IN  in_youtubeidvideo       VARCHAR(15),
    IN  in_title                  VARCHAR(200),
    IN  in_rating           DOUBLE,
    IN  in_viewcount        INT
)
BEGIN 

     INSERT INTO Video 
     (                
       YoutubeIdVideo,      
       Title,               
       Rating,              
       ViewCount,                     
       DataAdded,
       ConvertedFlag
     )

     VALUES 
     (
       in_youtubeidvideo,                
       in_title,             
       in_rating,        
       in_viewcount,
       CURDATE(),
       false
     );
END
```

---

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AxWaveConnection"].ToString()))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("InsertVideo", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("out_scope_id", scopeID);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("in_youtubeidvideo", VideoId));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("in_title", Title));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("in_viewcount", ViewCount));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("in_rating", Rating));

                cmd.Parameters["out_scope_id"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;


                try
                {
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    scopeID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["out_scope_id"].Value);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    scopeID = -1;        //Duplicate Record
                }



                conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting.

Comment: your are not returning any `output` from `procedure`

Comment: FUNCTION youtubedb.SCOPE_IDENTITY does not exist

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to set the value of the parameter in your proc; the last line in your stored proc should read like this:

```
select out_scope_id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

BTW: SCOPE_IDENTITY() is a MS SQL Server function; not a MySQL function.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @@IDENTITY AS 'Identity';
GO
```